# Why does ^M get appended to all updated lines in a git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I made some changes in my source file. When i try to see the diff using

```
git diff src/core/src/authentication.rs
```

The diff on the console is having `^M` appended to all the lines I edited.

```
+            Some(b) => {^M
+                Ok(b)^M
+            }^M
+        }^M
     }
```

I checked out in notepad to see if I can see something there and clean it up but was not visible there with any encoding I tried. I read [somewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134695/what-is-the-m-character-called) that it is a `\r` but not sure. Could not replace/find it in vim.
However this does not happen in all the files I see a `diff` for. Why is this happening? I guess this is not part of my source code and only something to do with git.

**Edit:** I use vim as my editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary reason is character sequences used to represent line breaks. In windows, a line break is represented by `\r\n`. So, when we edit a text (created on windows) on a Unix/Linux editor like VIM, the editor sees an extra character (since line break in UNIX is `\n`) and tries to render it. The output turns out to be ^M.

One way to deal with it on vim is

```
:set ff=unix
:wq
```

On a different note, its a standard practice as mentioned in [github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-all) to use "\n" as a new line character in git based repos. In order to set that by default, add this to your global git config settings.

```
$git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did help. And yes I might have used Windows as well.